# Averaging multiple images in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to average 300 .tif images with this code :

```
import os, numpy, PIL
from PIL import Image

# Access all PNG files in directory
allfiles=os.listdir(os.getcwd())
imlist=[filename for filename in allfiles if  filename[-4:] in[".tif",".TIF"]]

# Assuming all images are the same size, get dimensions of first image
w,h = Image.open(imlist[0]).size
N = len(imlist)

# Create a numpy array of floats to store the average (assume RGB images)
arr = numpy.zeros((h,w,3),numpy.float)

# Build up average pixel intensities, casting each image as an array of floats
for im in imlist:
    imarr = numpy.array(Image.open(im),dtype=numpy.float)
    arr = arr+imarr/N

# Round values in array and cast as 16-bit integer
arr = numpy.array(numpy.round(arr),dtype=numpy.uint16)

# Generate, save and preview final image
out = Image.fromarray(arr,mode="RGB")
out.save("Average.tif")
```

And it gives me a TypeError like that :

```
imarr = numpy.array(Image.open(im),dtype=numpy.float)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'TiffImageFile'
```

I understand that it doesn't really like to put a TIF image in the numpy array (it also doesn't work with PNG images). What should I do ? Splitting each image into R, G and B arrays to average and then merge everything seems too memory consuming.

Comment: Your problem is what you are passing to numpy in that line. You are trying to pass Image.open(im), which is a "TiffImageFile" type, and not accepted by float(). I haven't worked with PIL, but I see in internet that Image.load(im) might be what you are looking for. Otherwise, try and see if the object "im" could have something like im.data or so.

Comment: And I would be very surprised if "The Python Imaging Library" didn't have a method to average images already, by the way. Maybe you are just trying to learn how to do it yourself?

Comment: It should work as is, checked right now with PIL (pillow 2.9.0) and numpy 1.9.2.

Comment: I upgraded my numpy from 1.8.2 to 1.9.2 but it didn't change anything. I'm really wondering why since we run the same program with the same versions of PIL and numpy.

Comment: @Jblasco , PIL provides a blend method, which I used in another averaging program. I believe the code above (once it'll work) will provide a better result for a large number of pictures to average. I will investigate on your suggestions even if this code should work (see answer below)

Comment: I ran your code inside a virtualenv with just numpy and pillow there, both for py2 and py3.